# shopify assets, file structure and naming conventions

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

I am using Shopify to develop my e-commerce site and I am a little confused about assets.

Do I just dump all my JavaScript, css and images in the assets folder or can I have sub folders for each of them inside the assets folder?

Do I need to end every file name in .liquid?

If I can make subfolders would I use a relative path like this?

```
{{ 'css/default.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just upload all assets (images, CSS, JS, or any other file pertaining to the theme of your website) into the assets folder. You then just reference it by the filename.

Sub-folders are not possible at this time, but it's something I think a lot of Shopify customers would appreciate. I personally like a clean folder structure.

**CSS:**

```
{{ 'styles.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
```

**JS:**

```
{{ 'modernizr.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

**Referencing images or other assets in the CSS:**

```
{{ 'background.jpg' | asset_url }}

div#myDIV {
  background: url({{ 'background.jpg' | asset_url }}) center center no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: What about the naming convention why do I add .liquid to the end of files? or when I should say?

Comment: You add .liquid to the end of any CSS or JS file when you use any of the Liquid tags inside of that file. For example, you could add .liquid to your CSS file, and set variables inside of it. You could set {% assign mycolor = "#121212" %} at the top of your CSS file, and use that variable anywhere in that file. Example: .myclass { color: {{ mycolor }}; }

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense, can I just store the images on my server and use an absolute path to them or is that discouraged?

Comment: You could, but the Shopify CDN may load things quicker. I don't see an issue doing that though.